# Roslyn: Convert C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

I have the case wherein I need to convert a C#- to a VB.NET project. (I want to automate this, so I cannot use an online tool or something similar)

There is [a "Paste as C#/VB" sample visual studio extension](https://github.com/akimboyko/MetaProgramming/tree/master/MetaProgramming/MetaProgramming.RoslynCTP) which seemed to be able to do this.

I tried converting this class:

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Lorem
        /// </summary>
        public void Lorem()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But it ended up with this:

```
Namespace TestApplication

    Class Class1

        ''' <summary> Lorem </summary>        Public Sub Lorem()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

It does not only happen when XML-documentation comments are provided, but sometimes also when inheriting other classes etc.

Here's the code that handles the convertion of the sample:

csharpToVisualBasicConverter.Convert returns a SyntaxNode instance.

```
private void PasteAsVB()
{
    var csharpCode = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);

    var tree = CS.SyntaxTree.ParseText(csharpCode);
    var visualBasicCode = csharpToVisualBasicConverter.Convert(tree);

    var start = wpfTextView.Selection.SelectedSpans.Min(s => s.Start).Position;
    var end = wpfTextView.Selection.SelectedSpans.Max(s => s.End).Position;
    var span = Span.FromBounds(start, end);

    wpfTextView.TextBuffer.Replace(span, visualBasicCode.ToFullString());
}
```

As there is no exception when calling the convert method, I assume the method returns a valid SyntaxNode and the SyntaxNode.ToFullString() method or an encoding issue messes up the line breaks etc.

Did anybody experience this issue before and find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed an application 7 years ago in VB.NET and I had to integrate a component into it whose SDK was written in C# only. The application that I had to integrate was reasonably large amd complex. I used this product to convert the C# to VB.NET and whilst the finished product did require some tweaking and some thorough testing, I don't recall the process being particularly harrowing. The outcome was excellent. The application worked well and it is still going strong today.

http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html

Comment: As there may not be a definitive solution to my problem and because this product looks like the most solid one, I marked this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I've also used their Instant C# product to go the other way (VB.NET=>C#) and was able to convert a hefty solution without any significant problems. This was back in 2007 but I'd definitely go give them a shot if I had to do it again.

Comment: This does not convert Razor codes (.cshtml to .vbhtml) or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

FYI there is now a Roslyn Code Converter add-in for Visual Studio 2015.2+:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter

The web version is [here](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/) and the repo is [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter).

Answer (score 1):

SharpDevelop has a menu doing that conversion for the entire project. You can automate it interacting with the GUI (simulating mouse clicks) or, since it is open source, you can find the method called to do the conversion and call automatically with a special command line argument you can add and pass to SharpDevelop.
P.S.- That's the way developerfusion does the conversion (you can see in "Known Issues" a clear reference to #develop).

Answer (score 0):

I use the online tool http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
This seems to handle whole classes without an error.

Comment: I know about this tool, but I cannot use it because I have to automate the process (with my own visual studio extension), so I need to do it by code. If you know about any (working) alternatives, please let me know.

Comment: I did notice bugs in the past, but more recently i have not come across any.

Answer (score 0):

You don't compile to VB. Languages used by the .NET Framework compile to [CIL code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), which you could decompile to VB.NET. The results would be ugly.

Instead, use a [conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). Your sample code gave me this:

```
Namespace TestApplication
    Class Class1
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Lorem
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub Lorem()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Roslyn is be able to parse C# code to a node tree, which the extension I use uses to convert the code to VB (see the classes under CSharpToVisualBasicConverter/Converting).
I just answered to Steve Lawrence why I cannot use the tool you posted.

Comment: The tool I posted says it's based on [#develop editor](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). Perhaps you should see how they do it. By the way, your original question states "I have the case that I need to convert a C#- to a VB.NET project." That makes it sounds like a one time deal. You did not mention needing to do it from an extension as a requirement. Make **sure** you provide enough details in your question so you don't waste peoples' time.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.
I added the requirement to the question, I just didn't expect answers mentioning different tools as I asked about Roslyn specifically.

Comment: [“A compiler is a computer program that transforms source code written in a programming language (the source language) into another computer language (the target language, often having a binary form known as object code).”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) So yes, you *can* compile C# to VB.

Comment: @svick There's no need to split hairs and confuse the issue. When we're talking about the .NET Framework, compiling means going to CIL code. That's the common usage. Compiling has the common meaning that you are converting to a lower level. In this case, "translating" would be a much more accurate and less confusing term than "compiling".