# How to translate this VB.NET code to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to translate this VB.NET code to C#, but I'm new with C#.

This is my code VB.NET code:

```
 Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowPos" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As Integer, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, _
        ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer

 Private Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = &H1
 Private Const SWP_NOMOVE As Integer = &H2

 Private Shared ReadOnly HWND_TOPMOST As New IntPtr(-1)
 Private Shared ReadOnly HWND_NOTOPMOST As New IntPtr(-2)
 Private windows As New WindowInteropHelper(Me)

 Public Function MakeTopMost()
     SetWindowPos(windows.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
 End Function
```

And this is my C# Code:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
 public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(string hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

 private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
 private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;


 public void MakeTopMost()
 {
     SetWindowPos(windows.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
 }
```

> Error in MakeTopMost(): invalid Arguments

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Don't you have to use `0x1` instead of `&H1` in C#?

Comment: An hexdecimal constant in c# is written as 0x1;

Comment: O it works thanks, only i need to translate the  MakeTopMost() function, the "or" i think is bad

Comment: Have you asked [Roslyn yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679796/roslyn-convert-c-sharp-to-vb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
    private WindowInteropHelper windows = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

    public void MakeTopMost()
    {
        SetWindowPos(windows.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
    }
```

It shouldn't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks :D but, my Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib is correctly in my c# code?

Comment: I try with your code but the SetWindowPos function is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal numbers start with `0x`:

```
private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
```

Comment: o this work but mi problem is in the function MakeTopMos(): Error: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'

Comment: | is the bitwise or operator in c#.

Comment: yea i have this :D but my Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib is correctly in my c# code? because i have error there

Answer (score 0):

For the `MakeTopMost()` function you need to use a single | not two, as two translate to "OrAlso" which can only be used in a conditional. Here's the completed code (as reflected from the comment thread)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
private readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
private WindowInteropHelper windows = new WindowInteropHelper(this); 

public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(string hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

public void MakeTopMost()
{
    SetWindowPos(windows.handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D but, my Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib is correctly in my c# code? because i have error there

Comment: with | you should not get the error, is it a different error now?

Comment: Yes i have error in my  SetWindowPos  Invalids arguments :C

Comment: Can you place attach a screenshot of this new error? I believe it must be `windows.handle` and other subsequent values

Comment: I put the image in my question :D

Comment: The error is caused because your are passing `HWND_TOPMOST` which is of datatype `IntPtr` not integer. just go to the declaration of your SetWindowsPos and change the parameter to IntPtr (I'm updating my code for that)